# During reboot my screen goes black, how long should I wait before hard reset?

Tags: boot, restart

For whatever reasons I need to reboot my laptop every 5 days now. Normally it is suspended/resumed a couple/few times a day. Sometimes during reboot my screen goes black for a long period. How long should I wait before performing a hard reset (holding power button down for 10 seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are there is a "stop job" running in the background or an input inhibitor activated. You should wait 2 minutes for them to end normally before forcing an abend (abnormal ending) with a hard reboot (holding the power key down for 10 seconds).

If this problem happens frequently to you, try closing all your open applications before you reboot.

Comment: I would also suggest using Sysrq keys (REISUB etc) to restart; and using the power-button only if absolutely necessary.